# Cloud Endpoints API does not authorise Google APIs Explorer after upgrading to App Engine 1.9.0

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-cloud-endpoints

I use the Google APIs Explorer to test my Cloud Endpoint API running on the local dev server. I have authentication turned on:

```
@Api(
name = "testapi",
version = "1.0",
description = "Test API",
clientIds = { ApiConstants.WEB_CLIENT_ID, ApiConstants.ANDROID_CLIENT_ID,
    ApiConstants.IOS_CLIENT_ID, ApiConstants.EXPLORER_ID },
audiences = { ApiConstants.ANDROID_AUDIENCE })
public class TestAPI
{
     @ApiMethod(name = "TextObject.get", path = "testobject/{id}")
     public TestObject get(@Named("id") Long id, User user) throws OAuthRequestException
     {
          if (user == null)
          {
                    throw new OAuthRequestException(
            "No User specified when calling protected API method.");
          }
          ...
```

where ApiConstants.EXPLORER_ID is set to:

```
    public static final String EXPLORER_ID = com.google.api.server.spi.Constant.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID;
```

Everything worked fine in 1.8.9, and it works fine again when downgrading to 1.8.9. In 1.9.0, I get a null user in the code, and the "This method requires you to be authenticated." message in the explorer, even after logging in on the slider.

For now, I'll just hold off upgrading to 1.9.0, but I do want to upgrade at some stage to try out the Modules API.

Any ideas? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyone? Please help! Thanks :)

Comment: Wondering if you got this sorted out? I am encountering the same issue

Comment: No, I just downgraded. Hopefully someone from Google will give us a hand.